# Id duplicates when using templates in parse / backbone / js / html

Tags: html, parsing, templates, backbone.js, duplicates

I get duplicate ids when I set the views like so in my render function

```
var template = _.template($("#user-login-template").html(), {});
this.$el.html(template);
```

The html looks like this after running the render function, before runing the render function. Beforehand, the `<div class ="app">` is empty (as it should be). It copy pasted the code from template and therefore the ids into the div.

```
<div class="app">
<input type="text" id="signup-username" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="password" id="signup-password" placeholder="Create a Password"/>                                                                                                                                                              
<button id="signUpBtn">Sign Up</button>
<button id="logInBtn">Login</button>
</div>
<!-- Templates -->
<!-- Login Template -->
<script type="text/template" id="user-login-template">
    <input type="text" id="signup-username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="password" id="signup-password" placeholder="Create a Password"/>
    <button id="signUpBtn">Sign Up</button>
    <button id="logInBtn">Login</button>
</script>
```

For reference, this is what my whole view looks like

```
var LogInView = Parse.View.extend({
    el: '.app',
    events: {
        "click .signUpBtn": "signUp",
        "click .logInBtn": "logIn"
    },
    initialize: function (){
        this.render()
    },
    logIn: function () {
        //To Do
    },
    render: function () {
        var template = _.template($("#user-login-template").html(), {});
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
});
```

Comment: An `id` attribute inside a `<script type="text/template">` container isn't an `id` attribute at all, it is just a piece of unparsed character data. The HTML snippet in your question only contains one `#signUpBtn`, the `<button id="signUpBtn">Sign Up</button>` inside the `<script>` isn't HTML at all. Is that the underlying problem you're worried about?

Comment: Yea, I'm concerned about ids ( "signUpBtn", "loginBtn") appearing in my html twice after rendering the iew. Webstorm (my IDE ) gives me a "Duplicate id reference" error  when I inspect the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Webstorm is complaining about the `id`s inside the `<script>` then it is wrong and you have three options:

1. Get a new IDE that has a better understanding of HTML.
2. Figure out how to reconfigure Webstorm to know what HTML really is. There must be a way to beat some sense into Webstorm, this sort of thing is very common these days.
3. Ignore the warnings (yuck).

Things inside `<script>` are not HTML and are not part of the DOM. Ask the browser what `$('input[type=text]').length` is after your template is rendered and you'll get `1` since the

```
<input type="text" id="signup-username" placeholder="Username"/>
```

inside the `<script>` isn't HTML, it is just text. You can even check the [HTML specification of `<script>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html):

> **Permitted contents**
>   Non-replaceable character data

Non-replaceable character data is not HTML, it is just text.